# how can i put data in label , value(Vue JS)

Tags: vue.js

I started to learn Vue.js, I m trying to create a pie-Chart in my project. Also using (apexchart). I got data from Axios. I would like to show data inside label and value, how can I manage it. This is app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" /> -->
    <NavBar msg="Rick & Morty" />
    <PieChart
      :data="[
        { label: 'Human', value: 60 },
        { label: 'B', value: 40 },
        { label: 'C', value: 20 },
        { label: 'D', value: 10 }
      ]"
    />
    <Profile msg="Justin Rolland" />
  </div>
</template>



<script>
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue";
// import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import PieChart from "./components/PieChart.vue";
import Profile from "./components/Profile.vue";
import axios from 'axios';


export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    // HelloWorld,
    NavBar,
    PieChart,
    Profile
  },
   mounted() {
    axios
      .get("/data/episodes.json")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the directives, you can use string interpolation.

```
:data="[
        { label: `${data.label}`, value: 60 },
        { label: 'B', value: 40 },
        { label: 'C', value: 20 },
        { label: 'D', value: 10 }
      ]"
```

You will need to store the Axios `response.data` in `data` in the component.